# Extract date and time separately from a time with time zone column

Tags: select, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.3 with the following column

```
....,
  created_at time with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
...,
```

When I do a `select created_at from trails;` I get this

```
"02:32:44.62054-05"
```

How can I get the date in this format dd-mm-yyyy (01-11-2015)? I have tried `select created_at::date from trails;` but I get this error

```
ERROR: cannot cast type time with time zone to date
```

I changed to `select date(created_at) from trails;` and got this error

```
ERROR:  function date(time with time zone) does not exist
```

I want to do one select statement that will get the date and time separately in the format dd-mm-yyyy and hh:nn:ss in two columns i.e. `select date(created_at) as date, time(created_at) as time from trails;`

Comment: The column stores **`time`**. How do you think it's possible to extract a date from it? Do you have any other column that stores the `date` as well?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i will have to add a new column for date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html):

```
Name                       Description                        Low Value      High Value
time [(p)] with time zone  times of day only, with time zone  00:00:00+1459  24:00:00-1459
```

It would appear that the data type you have chosen for this column does not hold any "Date" value. What you are trying is not possible.